# How can I get all whitespaces in UTF-8 in Python?

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, how to list all characters matched by POSIX extended regex `[:space:]`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921365/in-python-how-to-list-all-characters-matched-by-posix-extended-regex-space)

How can I get a list of all whitespaces in UTF-8 in Python? Including non-breaking space etc. I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: http://www.bogofilter.org/pipermail/bogofilter/2003-March/001889.html

Comment: what do you mean by "a list of whitespaces"

Comment: I think this question should answer yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921365/in-python-how-to-list-all-characters-matched-by-posix-extended-regex-space

Comment: For ASCII, it's `string.whitespace`.

Comment: You mean the unicode code points, right? UTF-8 is just an encoding.

Comment: Heads up - you accepted my answer while I was in the middle of making a major edit.  You want to read the new version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`unicodedata.category`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category) will tell you the category code for any given character; the characters you want have code `Zs`.  There doesn't appear to be any way to extract a list of the characters within a category except by iterating over all of them:

```
>>> for c in xrange(sys.maxunicode+1):
...     u = unichr(c)
...     if unicodedata.category(u) == 'Zs':
...         sys.stdout.write("U+{:04X} {}\n".format(c, unicodedata.name(u)))
... 
U+0020 SPACE
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

(Note: if you do this test using Python 3.4 or later, MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR will not appear in the list.  Python 2.7 shipped with data from Unicode 5.2; this character was reclassified as general category Cf ("formatting control") in Unicode 6.3, which is the version that Python 3.4 used for its data.  See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/12/01/when-is-an-identifier-not-an-identifier-attack-of-the-mongolian-vowel-separator/ and https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2013/13004-vowel-sep-change.pdf for more detail than you probably require.)

You may also want to include categories `Zl` and `Zp`, which adds

```
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
```

And you almost certainly do want to include all of the ASCII control characters that are normally considered whitespace -- for historical reasons (I presume), these are in category `Cc`.

```
U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION  ('\t')
U+000A LINE FEED (LF)        ('\n')
U+000B LINE TABULATION       ('\v')
U+000C FORM FEED (FF)        ('\r')
U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)  ('\f')
```

The other 60-odd `Cc` characters should *not* be considered whitespace, *even if* their official name makes it sound like they are whitespace.  For instance, `U+0085 NEXT LINE` is almost never encountered in the wild with its official meaning; it's far more likely to be the result of an erroneous conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8 of `U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS`.

A closely-related question is "what does `\s` match in a Python regular expression?" Again the best available way to answer this question is to iterate over all characters:

```
>>> s = re.compile(ru"^\s$", re.UNICODE)
>>> for c in range(sys.maxunicode+1):
...   u = unichr(c)
...   if s.match(u):
...      sys.stdout.write("U+{:04X} {}\n".format(
...        c, unicodedata.name(u, "<name missing>")))
U+0009 <name missing>
U+000A <name missing>
U+000B <name missing>
U+000C <name missing>
U+000D <name missing>
U+001C <name missing>
U+001D <name missing>
U+001E <name missing>
U+001F <name missing>
U+0020 SPACE
U+0085 <name missing>
U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
U+1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
U+2000 EN QUAD
U+2001 EM QUAD
U+2002 EN SPACE
U+2003 EM SPACE
U+2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+2007 FIGURE SPACE
U+2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+2009 THIN SPACE
U+200A HAIR SPACE
U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR
U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
U+202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

(I don't know why `unicodedata.name` doesn't know the control characters' names.  Again, if you do this test using Python 3.4 or later, MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR will not appear in the list.)

This is all of the `Z*` characters, all of the `Cc` characters that are generally agreed to be whitespace, and five extra characters that are *not* generally agreed to be whitespace, U+001C, U+001D, U+001E, U+001F, and U+0085.  Inclusion of the last group is a bug, but a largely harmless one, since *using* those characters for anything is *also* a bug.

Comment: Unicode regex can handle the different categories used for whitespace: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921365/in-python-how-to-list-all-characters-matched-by-posix-extended-regex-space/8922773#8922773

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Treating U+001C through U+001F as whitespace is, well, I can see why they did it, and it's probably harmless, but it's still wrong.  Treating U+0085 as whitespace is just plain wrong for reasons stated above.  (IMNSHO the only approach to control characters that makes sense nowadays is to reassign U+0080 through U+009F according to their Windows-1252 definitions -- even when processing some other encoding -- and treat U+0000..U+0008, U+000E..U+001F, and U+007F as indicative of file corruption.)

Comment: It's true that NEL is usually an error, but [the Unicode standard, §5.8](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch05.pdf) says, "CR, LF, CRLF, and NEL should be treated the same on input and in interpretation. Only on output is it necessary to distinguish between them.", which suggests they should all be considered whitespace.

Comment: The Unicode standard contains much which reflects an idealized view of the world.  If you do that in real life you will fail to process people's documents correctly.  Note for example how http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#space-character does not include NEL in its enumeration, and how http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#misinterpreted-for-compatibility specifically requires that a document whose encoding is declared as ISO 8859.1 must be interpreted as if it were Windows-1252 instead.  (My position is even more drastic, I admit.)

Comment: @Zack: if you encountered NEL in **Unicode string** then you should treat it as whitespace (at least Perl, Python regex engines do). In practice it is very rare and it might point to incorrectly decoded text. You should fix the decoding process instead of changing the meaning of regexes.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian By the time you see the incorrectly recoded text, odds are it is too late to fix the decoding process.  "[You didn't write that awful page. You're just trying to get some data out of it.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)"

Comment: Do you know why `U+180E MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR` is included in the first list, but not the second? It seems that the regex doesn't match "all the Z*" characters as you stated.

Comment: @Antimony U+180E is in category Zs according to python 2.7's `unicodedata` (corresponding to Unicode 5.2), but it's in category Cf according to python 3.7's `unicodedata` (Unicode 11). Without knowing anything else, I would guess that MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR should never have been categorized as whitespace, and `re` and `unicodedata` are a little out of sync in python 2.7.

Comment: @Antimonly Hmm, actually `\s` *does* match U+180E in 2.7.  I must have fatfingered my original tests.  Answer edited.

Answer (score 3):

`Zs` category might not be enough:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import unicodedata

import regex # $ pip install regex

for i in xrange(sys.maxunicode + 1):
    u = unichr(i)
    if regex.match(u"[[:space:]]", u):
        try:
            name = unicodedata.name(u)
        except ValueError:
            name = ""
        print("{:9s} {} {}".format(repr(u), unicodedata.category(u), name))
```

#### Output

```
u'\t'     Cc 
u'\n'     Cc 
u'\x0b'   Cc 
u'\x0c'   Cc 
u'\r'     Cc 
u' '      Zs SPACE
u'\x85'   Cc 
u'\xa0'   Zs NO-BREAK SPACE
u'\u1680' Zs OGHAM SPACE MARK
u'\u180e' Zs MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR
u'\u2000' Zs EN QUAD
u'\u2001' Zs EM QUAD
u'\u2002' Zs EN SPACE
u'\u2003' Zs EM SPACE
u'\u2004' Zs THREE-PER-EM SPACE
u'\u2005' Zs FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
u'\u2006' Zs SIX-PER-EM SPACE
u'\u2007' Zs FIGURE SPACE
u'\u2008' Zs PUNCTUATION SPACE
u'\u2009' Zs THIN SPACE
u'\u200a' Zs HAIR SPACE
u'\u2028' Zl LINE SEPARATOR
u'\u2029' Zp PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
u'\u202f' Zs NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
u'\u205f' Zs MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
u'\u3000' Zs IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

Answer (score 0):

The list of offical space characters in the unicode database is defined through the 'Zs' categorie:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm

I am not sure if there is a functionality in Python's unicodedata module. I doubt: you can look over all characters and check their category against 'Zs'.